# RewriteRule for converting hex2bin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bin2hex

Is it possible to convert a hex value within a historical Url back to the de-hexed version (original ordernumber) for the new Url within a RewriteRule?

Assuming: `3830363234` = `80624`

from:

```
https://m.example.com/item/3830363234
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/search?sSearch=80624
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, for example with a [rewrite map](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html). In your case as historical data might be complete, even a static text file might suffice, otherwise using an executable shell script should be able to do it.

Comment: What is the relationship "3830363234 = 80624"? It is simply a one to one mapping? You mention "hex2bin" (which doesn't seem to apply) and "de-hexed version" (whatever that means?) - so is there some mathematical mapping from one to the other? How many URLs do you need to redirect? Or is it just this one?!